# Jquery contenteditable for all cells not rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, html-table

I create a table by adding rows and columns with JS and Jquery.
This is my code:

```
 function AddColumnToDataTable(){
      $('#tableHeader').append("<th> Header </th>").attr("contenteditable", true); 
// Add a new ColumnHeader and set the property "editable"
    }

    function AddRowToDataTable(){
      var count = $('#tableHeader').find("th").length; 
// Get the count of Columns in the table

      var newRow = $('#tableBody').append("<tr></tr>"); 
// Add a new Row

      for(var i = 0; i < count ; i++){
          newRow.find('tr').last().append("<td> Content </td>").attr("contenteditable", true); 
// Fill the cells with a default text and set the property "editable"
      }
    }
```

So my question is, how can I write the code, that each cell is editable? At the moment, when I click, the whole row goes editable? Each cell should have that property.

I found a code that could help:

```
//$('table th:nth-child(4)').attr("contenteditable", true)
```

This makes the 4th header/cell editable, but how can I use it, each new created header/cell is the nth-child?

Comment: I'm no jquery expert, but since you use .append() to insert a html string, might as well try the string '<td contenteditable="true"> Content </td>', since I think that jquery returns the last row after .append(), so you are setting contenteditable to that row instwead of the new element.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery append function doesn't return the new [appended] element, rather it returns the element that was appended to, hence the error in your code. Regardless, it's easier just to set the attribute manually in the append string. So, change this line:

```
newRow.find('tr').last().append("<td> Content </td>").attr("contenteditable", true);
```

To this:

```
newRow.find('tr').last().append("<td contenteditable="true"> Content </td>")
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```
$('table td').last().attr("contenteditable", true);
```